# "Make" not recognizing hdf5 using Intel OneAPI Fortran Compiler

Tags: bash, fortran, intel-fortran

Constructing a program for scientific research using .sh bash on MacOS terminal. Ran cmake to build the program, specifying the build path to Intel's Fortran compiler. However, after assembling the mod files using cmake, attempting to run "make" leads to the error:

```
error #7013: This module file was not generated by any release of this compiler.   [HDF5]
    use hdf5, ONLY : HSIZE_T
```

Best I am able to tell, this error is due to "make" attempting to use gfortran instead of the Intel Fortran Compiler, but the CMake build was created using the correct compiler, and the make command isn't appearing to use the same tags. Is there a "make-specific" tag in bash I need to add to get it to see the Intel compiler, or could this issue be caused by some other factor?

Unsure if relevant, but to add, there are errors that follow, but they are dependent on the HSIZE_T value from the error above, so it may be due to that value failing to be initialized:

```
error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HSIZE_T]
        integer(HSIZE_T) :: dims(MAXIODIM) = 0 !Dimension information
```

Comment: Was the HDF5 installation built with a release of the Intel Fortran compiler?

Comment: We need more detail - how did you configure cmake (what is the build path to Intel's Fortran compiler), and what is the output from compiling?

Comment: HDF5 was built using Homebrew, not the Intel Compiler.

cmake was configured with the tags "FC='/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/latest/mac/bin/intel64/ifort'"
"-DALLOW_INVALID_COMPILERS=ON"

Comment: The error message is from the Intel Fortran compiler (ifort) not gfortran or make, and it's saying that HDF5 wasn't built with the Intel compiler. You appear to agree that it wasn't, so can you clarify what your specific problem with that situation is?

Comment: The instructions for the program implied that this wouldn't be an issue, so it hadn't crossed my mind that the error was griping about that. Forgive the naive question, but would I go about building hdf5 through OneAPI directly or via bash and just calling OneAPI?

Comment: Because you are using a module, the installation must be compatible with your compiler in a much more specific way (even down to compiler versions at times). This contrasts with Fortran 77-style library use (included header files, implicit interfaces only, etc.). Your best bet probably is to build HDF5 from source using the Intel compiler, but it may well be possible to get a compatible installation through OneAPI kits or package managers or elsewhere.